# Flask write a file to custom directory

Tags: python, flask

I want flask to write files in a subdir.

This works, it writes a `test.txt` file in the `flask_root/files` dir:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                                 
def index():
    with open('files/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("sometext")
```

But why won't this work ?

```
app.add_url_rule('/files/<filename>', endpoint='files')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                                 
def index():
    with open(url_for('files' filename='test.txt'), 'w') as f:
        f.write("sometext")
--
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/files/test.txt'
```

Comment: the path given for file open is wrong

Comment: So there is no way to let flask get the path without using the os lib?

Comment: `url_for` will generate url not abolute path of the file